# Загрузка в dataGridView вложенного класса из xml файла

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

Не могу вытащить из `<SPC_D_отсрочка_10>` значение 419,43.
Часть xml файла, который гружу:

```
<ITEM>
  <CODE>282424</CODE>
  <NAME>КИСЛОТА</NAME>
  <VENDOR>ОАО Марбиофарм</VENDOR>
  <VENDORBARCODE>4602876007181</VENDORBARCODE>
  <QTTY>96</QTTY>
  <VALID_DATE>01.12.2022 </VALID_DATE>
  <PACKQTTY>0</PACKQTTY>
  <MINQTTY>0</MINQTTY>
  <NDS>20</NDS>
  <HAS_TAGS>0</HAS_TAGS>
  <PRICES>
    <SPC_D_отсрочка_10>419,43</SPC_D_отсрочка_10>
  </PRICES>
  <XCODE></XCODE>
</ITEM>
```

код в C# которым заполняю dataGridView

```
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["ITEM"].Rows)
{
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); 
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["CODE"]; 
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["NAME"]; 
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["VENDOR"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["VENDORBARCODE"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["QTTY"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["VALID_DATE"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["PACKQTTY"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["MINQTTY"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["NDS"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["HAS_TAGS"];
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["SPC_D_отсрочка_10"];  
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["XCODE"];
}
```

Ругается

> Столбец "SPC_D_отсрочка_10" не принадлежит таблице ITEM.

Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Может быть проблема в кириллице? Убедитесь, что вы читаете файл в той же кодировке, в которой он записан. По умолчанию в методах чтения файлов в дотнете используется кодировка UTF-8. Следовательно, файл должен быть сохранен в этой же кодировке. Код загрузки данных из файла вы не показали, поэтому детальнее не подскажу. А еще лучше - не используйте кириллицу в именах тегов.

Comment: Я отформатировал ваш xml, и теперь сразу видно, что искомый узел находится внутри другого: `PRICES`. | Да, и покажите код, как этот xml попадает в DataTable.